# How can i store text area input of TinyMce text editor into mysql and retreive with same css effect

Tags: tinymce, text-editor, tinymce-5

I have input field of the text area, I need to write a paragraph with bold, italic characters. I used TinyMCE text editor for those CSS input effects. But plaintext is displaying when I store that input value into a database and retrieve it from a database. How can I get value with the same CSS?

Answer (score 0):

When you get content from TinyMCE, either by form submission or using `.getContent()` that content is an HTML string, and styling information like bold, italic, etc, should be included inline with the HTML.

If your content is not rendering later with that same styling, then it is likely one of two things is happening:

1. Your content is being sanitized (all HTML markup removed) when it is inserted into your database, and therefore is being saved in your db as a plain text string. Or...
2. Your HTML is being saved in the database correctly, but is being sanitized upon render. If you are passing HTML to something like a React or Angular component to be rendered on the page, often by default that HTML is sanitized for security reasons. There is usually a way to change this behavior, but it depends on what framework you are using.

Either way, content leaves TinyMCE as HTML, so you will likely want to review your database and/or content rendering settings.